# Canonical orientation of a complex manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-manifolds

It is clear to me that a complex manifold is orientable. However is there a canonical choice of one of the two possible orientation or is it just a matter of convention? And, if it is a convention, is there a universally accepted one ?

It seems to me that on a manifold of complex dimension $n$ using the complex structure $J$, both the choices
\begin{equation}
\{\partial_{x_1}, \ldots,\partial_{x_n},J\partial_{x_1}, \ldots,J\partial_{x_n}\}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\{\partial_{x_1},J\partial_{x_1}, \ldots,\partial_{x_n},J\partial_{x_n}\}
\end{equation}
are natural, but they result in opposite orientation for $n$ even.
Similarly, given a Kahler form $\Omega$, wedging it with itself $n$ times gives an orientation form, however defining $\Omega(X,Y)=g(X,JY)$ or $\Omega(X,Y)=g(JX,Y)$ seems to be a matter of convention, and the resulting orientation forms are opposite for $n$ odd.

Finally, as a special case of the question above, what is the standard orientation of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ as a complex manifold?

Comment: The orientation is different for _even_ $n$. The second choice may have the added advantage that the transition matrices are bloc matrices with blocs of the form $$\begin{pmatrix} a&-b\\b&a\end{pmatrix}$$ and so identifies nicely with complex $n\times n$ matrices.

Comment: @Olivier thanks, I have corrected that.

Comment: If $\omega$ is a choice of canonical orientation then in some sense so is $-\omega$ so this kind of problem is inescapable.